# Karate Api Testing with Maven and Jenkinsfile

Tags: cucumber, jenkins-pipeline, maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin, karate

I am pretty new to API testing. The software tester has pushed the API testing code to the gitlab.  what I am trying to do is to checkout the API testing code from gitlab and then run the testing using jenkins (with help of maven commands, I guess here we need to use maven)

My Jenkinsfile looks like this after the check out stage.

```
stage ("Build and testing") {
withMaven(
 maven: 'Maven3',
 mavenLocalRepo: '.repository') {
   sh  "mvn -f pom.xml clean install"
   sh  "mvn surefire-report:report"
   sh  "mvn  test -DargLine='-Dkarate.env=staging' -Dtest=Runs  -DfailIfNoTests=false"
```

the folder "src/test/java" contains karate-config.js and 
the folder  "src/test/java/Promotionproduct" contains feature file "promotions.feature" and a java file "Runs.java"

The contents of the Runs.java file is

```
package Promotionproduct;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import com.intuit.karate.junit4.Karate;
@RunWith(Karate.class)
public class Runs {
}
```

the building is working and is providing the 2 Artifacts  SNAPSHOT.jar  and SNAPSHOT.pom, I am not sure how to proceed after with this. The command

```
mvn surefire-report:report
```

is generating some report in the file "target/site/surefire-report.html" but it does not has any test result,

the command `mvn  test -DargLine='-Dkarate.env=staging' -Dtest=Runs  -DfailIfNoTests=false` is generating the file "Promotionproduct.Runs.txt" and "TEST-Promotionproduct.Runs.xml"  but does not have any test result. the Jenkins console says

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

it seems the either the promotions.feature and Runs.java is not executing properly. Software tester is getting the test result when is executing (might be runs.java) the tests with the selenium. Is there any specific commands need to be run in the command line for this?

Comment: impossible for anyone to figure without your whole setup. a guess is that your pom.xml is incorrect and the feature files are in src/test/java - read the docs carefully. best way to solve this is follow these instructions: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue